# Read Inbox Messages GROUP BY address

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hi guys I am using list fragments to replicate my inbox. And I am facing an issue while querying sms from inbox. The result I receive is not unique for address. For example if there are two messages from 222 then both of them will appear differently in list. What I want is to group them by their number but no luck. My function to query is given below:
Thanks in advance :)

```
    public Cursor getInboxList(){
        Cursor result=null;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        result=this.context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String [] {"body","address"}, null ,null,null);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: please post data structure or partial dump of table

Comment: Hi tony that is android inbox uri I dont know where to get it's table from but I have found the solution by:

Comment: `Cursor result=null;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        result= this.context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[]{"DISTINCT address","body"}, 
                "address IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (address", 
                null, null);`